# Call static function in Twig

Tags: twig

I am pretty new to Twig. I have a class called `Session` and a static function called `get` I want to return the content of `Session::get('user_name')`. Is it even possible without modifying anything?

I tried `{{ constant('Namespace\\Session::get("user_name")') }}` and `{{ Session.get('user_name') }}` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Twig Extension like below:

```
class CustomExtension extends \Twig_Extension {


    public function getFunctions() {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('static_call', array($this, 'staticCall')),
        );
    }

    function staticCall($class, $function, $args = array()) {
        if (class_exists($class) && method_exists($class, $function)) {
            return call_user_func_array(array($class, $function), $args);
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Usage in in twig:

```
{{ static_call('AppBundle\\Entity\\YourEntity', 'GetSomething', ['var1', 'var2']) }}
```

Comment: Register twig extension as a service in Symfony: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/twig_extension.html

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. I simply added the following code right after `new Twig_Enviroment($twig_loader)`

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($twig_loader);
$twig->addFunction('_call', new Twig_Function_Function(
    function($class, $function, $arguments = array())
    {
        return call_user_func(array($class, $function), $arguments);
    })
);
```

In Twig

```
{{ _call('Session', 'get', 'user_name')|raw }}
```